# What is the best storage for active-active linux cluster?

Tags: ubuntu, storage, cluster, drbd, ocfs2

We have a cluster with multiple ubuntu machines which are connected to a shared SAN storage. Initially we were using OCFS2 as file system but we were hit with so many issues and we couldn't find proper documentation or support therefore we have decided to move to another cluster system. So can you suggest the best system considering we need to keep all nodes as active and we want to move away from cluster aware filesystems?
We have looked at DRBD but it seems it's only used for Active-Passive setup.

Comment: Firstly there's nothing wrong with OCFS2, we've used it extensively for years on dozens of machines and there's plenty of documentation to be found. That said we don't do product/service recommendations on serverfault, which it clearly states in our FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

We're using [gfs2](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Global_File_System_2/ch-overview-GFS2.html) these days and are pretty happy with it.